# Uses for esoteric integral symbols

Tags: analysis, notation

A while ago, I was searching for a TeX package which would provide a double integral symbol with a circle which I could use to typeset some lecture notes on surface integrals.  I happened upon the [esint](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/esint/esint.pdf) package, which includes several integral symbols I had never seen before.  In particular, integral symbols with a square (`\sqint` and `\sqiint`), a sloped dash (`\fint`) and the very curious `\landupint` and `\landdownint`.  Is anyone familiar with any uses for these symbols?

---

**Added** (TB) Here's an image of the integral signs in question:

[image: integral signs]

Answer (score 7):

Well, `\sqint` is the quaternion integral and `\fint` is used for integral averages, if memory serves. I'll have to look around for the others, though.

Answer (score 6):

The one with the sloped dash is sometimes used to denote integral averages:

\fint_A $f(x)d\mu(x) = \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \int_{A} f(x) d\mu(x)$

Answer (score 6):

The circles with arrows are useful for contour-integrals in complex analysis.

The \landupint and \landdonwint are probably used to expres contourintegrals that go around a singularity by integrating around the boundary of half of a circle ($\partial B(x,\epsilon)$) and letting $\epsilon\to 0$. I've never seen that symbol being used in practice, but it's what the picture suggests.